# Localizing date on SSRS

Tags: date, reporting-services

I'm using the **d** Format on the date field

So when the report's Language is on German(**de**), July 22, 2012 appears as:

```
22.07.2012
```

When I switch the report's Language to English(**en**), July 22, 2012 appears as:

```
7/22/2012
```

How can I make the English date appear as **07/22/2012**? i.e. the dates should appear as two digits regardless of the month being two digits or single digit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [custom date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) such as MM/dd/yyyy. If you need custom format only for English report then you can use expression `=IIf (User!Language = "en", "dd\mm\yyyy", "d")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression in you report to show the date in dd/mm/yyyy format. Following screenshot shows date time with and without modification to the expression.

**Expression:**

```
=string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}",Fields!ModifiedDate.Value)
```

**Without modification**

[image: Without modification]

**With Modification:**
[image: With Modification]

Hope this helps!